# Java: Running a Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have the following JEE application set-up:

- WAR-1 contains the server web application (with the server implementation)
- WAR-2 contains the batch web application (with the batch)

Both WAR's run on a seperate application server each. How can I start a Spring batch (which is set up in WAR-2) from WAR-1 (application server)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can go through Spring Batch docs [runningJobsFromWebContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch provides an interface

```
org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher
```

using which you can trigger batch jobs. It is outside the scope of Spring Batch how you expose this invocation/triggering in your application.

One possible option is to expose an batch job trigger REST endpoint which the application in war1 can call.

```
private final org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry jobRegistry;
private final org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@POST
@Path("/batch/trigger/{batchJobName}")
@Consumes(ALL_MEDIA_TYPES)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response runBatchJob(@PathParam("batchJobName") String batchJobName) throws JobExecutionException {
    Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(batchJobName);
    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());
    Long jobExecutionId = execution.getId();
    return Response.ok().entity(jobExecutionId).build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this interesting approach. So I would basically just call the batch like a RESTful web service?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sub project of Spring Batch Admin called Spring Batch Integration.  It contains a number of components for using Spring Batch and Spring Integration together.  In that project are components for launching jobs via messages.  Using these components, you can maintain a decoupled deployment, launch the jobs in an event driven manor and scale them as needed.  This is the route I'd recommend.

You can read more about this project here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/tree/master/spring-batch-integration

You can also view a talk Gunnar Hillart and I did on Spring Batch Integration this past year at SpringOne2GX here: http://spring.io/blog/2014/01/14/springone2gx-2013-replay-integrating-spring-batch-and-spring-integration